# Why can't I submit a record to Zoho Sales Order API?

Tags: json, api, zoho

I'm trying to insert a record using the Zoho API, and I keep receiving a cryptic `INVALID_DATA` error message.

I've tried using their [sample code](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/v2/insert-records-examples.html#insert-salesorder) which, of course, produces another error. And the sample code they provide for running in Postman also produces an error.

Their docs are lacking and inconsistent, and nobody is getting back to me on their message boards, and I'm getting desperate as I need to have this done today. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

This is what I'm submitting via Postman

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Owner": {
                "id": "3938209039489388001"
            },
            "Contact_Name": {
                "id": "398129039938498309"
            },
            "Subject": "Test",
            "Product_Details": [
                {
                    "product": {
                        "id": "1234567"
                    },
                    "quantity": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the error response

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "code": "INVALID_DATA",
            "details": {
                "api_name": "product",
                "index": 0,
                "parent_api_name": "Product_Details"
            },
            "message": "invalid data",
            "status": "error"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: specifically, what example are you using? What endpoint, exactly?

Comment: https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Sales_Orders. However I figured it out and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to POST a product first, then grab that product ID and insert it under `Product_Details`. This is not documented, so I assumed the product would be created automatically, which it wasn't.